CS50(2024) - Finance. :( registering user succeeds and portfolio page is displayed - expected status code 200, but got 400
I am doing the CS50 course and am struggling to complete Pset9 - finance(2024). When I submit my code, the check 50 displays an error saying ":( registering user succeeds and portfolio page is displayed", the cause being "expected status code 200, but got 400."
I would really appreciate it if someone can take a look at the code below, and let me know if I am doing something wrong or just point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!
Here is my code for register in app.py:
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    """Register user"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.form.get("username")
        password = request.form.get("password")
        confirmation = request.form.get("confirmation")

        # Debugging output
        print(f"Username: {username}, Password: {password}, Confirmation: {confirmation}")

        # Validate form fields
        if any(not field for field in [username, password, confirmation]):
            return apology("FIELDS CANNOT BE EMPTY", 400)

        if not username.isalnum():
            return apology("USERNAME MUST ONLY CONTAIN ALPHABETS AND NUMBERS!", 400)

        if len(password) < 8:
            return apology("PASSWORD MUST CONTAIN AT LEAST 8 CHARACTERS!", 400)

        if not re.search("[a-zA-Z]", password) or not re.search("[0-9]", password) or not re.search("[!@#$%^&*()]", password):
            return apology("PASSWORD MUST CONTAIN ALPHABETS, NUMBERS, AND SYMBOLS!", 400)

        if password != confirmation:
            return apology("PASSWORDS DO NOT MATCH!", 400)

        # Check if username already exists
        user_exists = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)
        if len(user_exists) > 0:
            return apology("USERNAME ALREADY TAKEN!", 400)

        # Hash the password
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)

        # Insert new user into the database
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES (?, ?)", username, hashed_password)

        # Get the user’s id and log them in
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", username)
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]

        # Redirect to the homepage
        return redirect("/")

    # Render the registration page
    return render_template("register.html")

Here is my code for index in app.py:
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
    """Show portfolio of stocks"""
    user_id = session["user_id"]
    portfolio = db.execute("SELECT * FROM portfolios WHERE user_id = ?", user_id)
    cash_left = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = ?", user_id)

    if cash_left and "cash" in cash_left[0]:
        cash_left = float(cash_left[0]["cash"])
    else:
        cash_left = 0.0

    total_amount = 0.0

    try:
        for stock in portfolio:
            symbol = stock["symbol"]
            stock_info = lookup(symbol)

            if not stock_info or "price" not in stock_info:
                return apology("FAILED TO UPDATE THE STOCK PRICES!")

            current_price = float(stock_info["price"])
            stock_value = current_price * stock["shares"]

            stock.update({"current_price": current_price, "stock_value": stock_value})
            total_amount += stock_value
    except (ValueError, LookupError):
        return apology("FAILED TO UPDATE THE STOCK PRICES!")

    return render_template("index.html", portfolio=portfolio, cash_left=cash_left, total_amount=total_amount)

Here is register.html:
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Register
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/register" method="post">
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <input class="form-control mx-auto w-auto" id="confirmation" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" required>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}


Here is index.html:
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Homepage
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <div class="table-responsive-md">
        <table class="table mx-auto w-50">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-active">
                    <th scope="col">Company Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Symbol</th>
                    <th scope="col">No. of Shares</th>
                    <th scope="col">Buying Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">Current Price</th>
                    <th scope="col">STOCK VALUE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for stock in portfolio %}
                <tr class="table-light">
                    <td>{{ stock["name"] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock["symbol"] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock["shares"] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock["paid_price"] | usd }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock["current_price"] | usd }}</td>
                    <td>{{ stock["stock_value"] | usd }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-0 fw-bold text-end" colspan="5">CASH LEFT</td>
                    <td class="border-0 text-center">{{ cash_left | usd }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-0 fw-bold text-end" colspan="5">TOTAL</td>
                    <td class="border-0 text-center">{{ total_amount | usd }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

I also tried check the developer tools in chrome but could find andy status code showing 400
Check the image here
